# Sequential Bertrand game with differentiated goods, how to write the strategies of firm 2

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, dynamic-games

In a Bertrand competition with differentiated goods where firms set the prices sequentially, we have the following demand functions:

q1 is quantity of goods demanded for firm 1
q2 is quantity of goods demanded for firm 2
p1 and p2 are prices of goods for firm 1 and firm 2.

q1 = 16 - 2*p1 + p2
q2 = 16 - 2*p2 + p1

The marginal cost is 4. No fixed costs.

The profit function for firm 1 is: 
TR1 = p1*(16 - 2*p1 + p2) - (16 - 2*p1 + p2)*4

The profit function for firm 2 is: 
TR2 = p2*(16 - 2*p2 + p1) - (16 - 2*p2 + p1)*4

Firm 1 sets the price first, firm 2 sets the price after. It's a squential game.

How can I write the strategies of firm 2?

Isn't it just S(p1) = 6 + 1/4*p1 ?

How is p1 = p2 = 8 a Nash equilibrium?

Comment: Please consider formatting mathematical notations using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/70119).

Comment: It's about Bertrand competition, how can it be off-topic in economics? It's just about economics.

Comment: "**This question does not meet the standards for homework questions** as spelled out in the relevant meta posts. For more information, see our policy on homework question and the general FAQ."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the profit function of firm 2 in terms of prices $p_1$ and $p_2$.
Then, you can find $p_2^*(p_1)$, the optimal reaction of firm 2 for any observed price $p_1$.
Firm 1 anticipates this reaction. So you can plug $p_2^*(p_1)$ into the profit function of firm 1 and maximize it with respect to $p_1$.